# Create .txt output with numeric values separated by comma

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame:

```
numbers <- c(200.11, 201.12)
df <- data.frame(numbers)
```

I now want to create .txt file where the data has the following format:

```
200.11, 201.12, etc...
```

I wrote the following:

```
list <- c()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  list <- c(d$y[i], list)
}

write.table(list, "C:/Users/User/Dropbox/PROJECTEN/Lopend/24-03-outsource-assignment-vba/1.txt", sep="\t")
```

This gives me the output in rows but I need it all numbers after each other (instead of beneath each other)l. Any feedback on what I should change here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a single-row `data.frame` (`t`ransposed vector), you can just write it once.

```r
write.table(as.data.frame(t(numbers)), sep=",", col.names=FALSE, row.names=FALSE)
# 200.11,201.12
```

BTW: I think your `for` loop is equivalent to `list <- rev(df$y)`, but doing it in an inefficient (for R) way.